# how do i convert format of current time in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, strftime

i have been trying to use 'strftime()' with '%j' to get the current day's number of the year (0-365):

```
daynow = ("%d"% (datetime.day))
daynum =  (time.strftime("%j", time.gmtime(daynow)))

print (daynum)
```

but returns:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
%d format: a number is required, not getset_descriptor

what does this mean, what is a getset_descriptor and how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code to get day of the month, day of the year and week of the year  :

```
from datetime import datetime,date
today = datetime.now()
day_of_the_month = ("%d"% (today.day))
day_of_year = today.timetuple().tm_yday
week_of_the_year = today.isocalendar()[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`%d` is looking for a number. but `datetime.datetime.day` is feeding in an object

`Out[18]: <attribute 'day' of 'datetime.date' objects>`

So get the date of today. Then use that to do `.day`

```
import datetime
import time

today = datetime.datetime.now()
daynum = ("%d"% (today.day))

print (daynum)
```

will give output `19`

Comment: that partly worked thanks but it now says that it needs a integer not a string because i have my %d in quotation marks, how can i make this a number not a string

Comment: Yes. Just do ‘daynum = today.day’

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. WIth it, we get the number of days between first day of the year and today, by subtracting two dates properly formated.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

day = datetime.datetime.now().day
month = datetime.datetime.now().month
year = datetime.datetime.now().year

f_date = date(year, 1, 1)
l_date = date(year, month, day)
delta = l_date - f_date
print(delta.days)
```

This will output `352` (since today is 12/19/2018).